# How do you extract a file from an incoming POST

Tags: python, post, aiohttp

I have a strange case where I have a POST coming in with a file attached. I am using aiohttp as a server. Normally I would use a get to retrieve a file but that’s not possible in this situation. I can’t seem to find any documentation on retrieving a file over http using aiohttp.

Comment: Can you add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You need more reding through the documentation. Most of the time we have everything we need in it.

http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#file-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example assuming you've used a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```py
async def handle_file_upload(request):
    data = await request.post()
    print('parts:', data.keys())
    # assuming we have a file called foobar
    print('filename:', data['foobar'].filename)
    print('file object:', data['foobar'].file)
    print('file content:', data['foobar'].file.read())
    ...  # (return response etc.)
```

be careful about using code like this in the wild with no protection as I believe `await request.post()` will read all request data into memory. If someone does `curl -X POST --data-binary "@/dev/urandom"...` you'll be in big trouble.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.